# Relative-absolute positioning?

Tags: html, css, positioning

I'd like to position something relatively absolutely, e.g. taking it out of the document flow and adjusting its position a few pixels. What's a neat way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use `margin` to shift the absolutely positioned element.

**HTML:**

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolar sit amet.</p>
<p class="move">Lorem ipsum dolar sit amet.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolar sit amet.</p>
```

**CSS:**

```
p.move { color:red; position:absolute; margin:5px 0 0 5px; }
```

**Demo: [jsfiddle.net/KXCkV](http://jsfiddle.net/Marcel/KXCkV/)**

Answer (score 2):

You could put your relatively positioned item within an absolutely positioned container and use top, left, right, or bottom to move it wherever you need to.

Comment: Yeah, containers are what I'm trying to avoid. If there's no other choice though, that's fine too. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of what you need to do:

```
<div style="position: relative; width: 500px; height: 200px;">
    <div style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0;">Upper Left</div>
    <div style="position: absolute; right: 0; bottom: 0;">Lower Right</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Only way I could think to do this is to have the element styled in the document on page load and then finding its position and changing the style to `position:absolute`, setting the `top:` and `left:` properties programatically based on it's original location.

Comment: It absolutely cannot involve JavaScript. Or VBScript ;-)